# Move on position in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-search

I am developing an Android App in which i have **60 Items** which i have bind with `GridViewAdapter` which is display **9 Items Per Page** and working properly.

[image: GridView]

BUT

I want to make **search from that 60 Items** using **Name of Items** and want to focus on `EditText`.

I have done code but that search from **9 items** only which is currently displaying.

Is there any solution that make it perfect.

Your Help always Appreciated...

Comment: are you popping it out from DB or pulling through webservices ?

Comment: then not a big deal you need to Modify your query like Select * from "Table" where "name" like 'search name'

Comment: So i have fire query for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set filter when you pull data from database and whenever text changed in edittext change the question in sql

```
  Select * from table where name="nameFromEditText"
```

*means your collumns. Its not good to select all using *

or if you are using contentProvider construct proper question to db

```
 mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    URI // The content URI of the words table
    YOUR_COLUMNS_HERE,                        // The columns to return for each row
    NAME_OF_COLUMNS ,                   // Selection criteria
    ARGUMENTS_WHAT_NEED_TO_MATCH_TO_THESE_COLUMNS,                     // Selection criteria
  SORT_ORDER);
```

or you can implement filterable adapter to your gridView. Simply implement in GridViewAdapter Filterable interface and than you can filter anything you want.
[Example](http://www.mokasocial.com/2010/07/arrayadapte-filtering-and-you/) This example refers to listView but it can be used also with gridView.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution for this scenario is Run search query

```
Select * from TableName where Name="Given name from Edit text"
```

you can run this query in two way

1. if you want to run every time you type any char in edit text then over ride method

   addTextChangedListener
2. if you want to run query at the end of entered text and on Button then run Db query on click of button